# Morphology-like solution for big blobs of noise on a thresholded image(using Python and opencv)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

H!
I am working on a little image processing project and after the morphology step I don't wanna see any big noise on the object. But big blobs of noise still persist. Is there any way(except aggressive morphology) to just remove all black pixels that are within the white blob of pixels?
Image before morphology step:
[image]

Image after morphology step:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extract the big white shape with `findContours` (with options `RETR_EXTERNAL` and `CHAIN_APPROX_NONE`), then, fill the contour with `drawContours`.

Comment: Or `findContours` and fill the small black ones with white.